# Cumulaltive sum over time - does not end with the latest date

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

The graph is showing in the x axis a generic date table (a_datetable[Date]) and on the y axis the following measure for the cumulative sum of "certificates" over the date 'status_no6'[Status created]:

```
Cumulative sum by status date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('app_yearly_finances'[certificates]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('status_no6'),
        'status_no6'[Status created] <= MAX(a_datetable[Date]) && 'status_no6'[Status created] <> BLANK()
    )
)
```

Because the datetable[Date] contains dates till 2030 the graph is also prolonged till 2030 instead of breaking up at the last date of "status created".

I need to keep a generic datetable in the x axis to add other cumulative sums measures to the graph.

There is the option that I set a filter on the datetable to the latest date to shorten the graph which, however, I would need to adapt the filter every time I update my data.
Is there a way, to include this in the calculation? The goal is that the cumulative sum "certificates" over datetable[Date] the stops with the latest date of 'status_no6'[Status created].

Answer (score 0):

Capture the max available date and add that to your filter.
Something like:

```
Cumulative sum by status date = 
  var maxDate = CALCULATE( LASTDATE('status_no6'[Status created]), ALLSELECTED('status_no6') )
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM('app_yearly_finances'[certificates]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('status_no6'),
        'status_no6'[Status created] <= MAX(a_datetable[Date]) &&
        'status_no6'[Status created] <> BLANK() &&
        'status_no6'[Status created] <= maxDate
    )
)
```